# Explain how second order differential equations of the form $\ddot{y}+y=0$ exhibit osciallatory dynamics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, oscillatory-integral

I'm trying to build a skillset for research in computational neuroscience (and loving math even more as I go along) and have just jumped into the world of differential equations – very simple ones.

One of the models I've encountered is defined by the second order differential equation:

[image]

Which when integrated (with `scipy`) yields oscillatory dynamics [image].

I'm looking for an explanation of why oscillatory dynamics emerge from this form of differential equation. The same way the graph of $f(x)=2x$ is so clear, the best answer will relate the equation to the dynamics in such an intuitive way.

Comment: I would suggest a parametric plot of $t \mapsto (x(t),\dot{x}(t))$.

Comment: to answer the question for myself, or to make the question better? What software would I use to generate parametric plots?

Comment: For your own benefit. If you are familiar with the physics, look at the kinetic & potential energies...

Comment: Well, if you have $\ddot y + y = 0 \Rightarrow \ddot y = -y$. So when $y$ is large, its second derivative is more negative, pushing the function back down, and similarly when $y$ is below zero, the second derivative is positive, bringing it back up.

Comment: @copper.hat I don't see it: That's just an ellipse, could you elaborate?

Comment: @TokenToucan thanks . I get it now.

Comment: @copper.hat For reference, here's the plot: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mbdcjfwecc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A Bit of Intuition**

$\ddot{x}=-k^2x$ says that when $x\gt0$, the slope of $x$ is decreasing, and when $x\lt0$, the slope of $x$ is increasing. This means that $x$ is concave above the $x$-axis and convex below the $x$-axis. This is the behavior of a periodic function, but this behavior does not guarantee periodicity since this behavior is also exhibited by $\tanh(x)$

[image]

We need to solve the equation to prove periodicity.

**Full Solution**

$$
D^2+k^2=(D-ik)(D+ik)\tag{1}
$$
To invert the operator $D+ik$, note that
$$
\begin{align}
(D+ik)u=f
&\implies D\left(e^{ikx}u(x)\right)=e^{ikx}f(x)\\
&\implies u(x)=e^{-ikx}\int e^{ikx}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
we can apply $(2)$ for $k$ and $-k$ to $(1)$ to get
$$
\left(D^2+k^2\right)u=f
\implies u(x)=e^{ikx}\int e^{-2ikx}\int e^{ikx}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}
$$
Setting $f(x)=0$ in $(3)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
u(x)
&=c_1e^{ikx}+c_2e^{-ikx}\\[6pt]
&=(c_1+c_2)\cos(kx)+i(c_1-c_2)\sin(kx)\\[6pt]
&=b_1\cos(kx)+b_2\sin(kx)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
where $c_1,c_2$ come from the constants of integration in $(3)$.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you're asking but$\dots$

---

This is the equation of a spring: $$m\ddot x =-kx$$

By Hooke's law: The force ($F=m\ddot x$ by Newton's law) done by a spring is equal to a constant $k$ (hardness of the spring) times the displacement $x$ (from the equilibrium position). From this viewpoint, it's only natural that the solutions are oscillatory.

A solution could be written as $x=R\cos \left(\sqrt\frac{k}{m}t+\phi_0\right)$ where $R$ is the amplitude, $\sqrt\frac{k}{m}$ is called the natural frequency and $\phi_0$ is the initial phase.

The extra factor $mg$ in your equation, is the force of gravity: I suppose the spring is hanging from the ceilling.

Comment: this stems from my just being introduced to DEs. why cant i just double integrate?

Comment: In short: There's no concept of separation of variables for second order DEs (except in special cases). Why? Well, if you try to make some algebraic manipulation, you won't be able to get something of the form $f(x)dx=g(t)dt$ in order to integrate. This makes solving $n$th order linear differential equation (with linear coefficients) a bit more tricky. It requires a bit more of theory, but then the process  is a bit mechanical. Here's a *short* set of notes about these http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-HigherOrderLinEq.pdf

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} (\sin t) = -\sin t$$
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} (\cos t)  = -\cos t$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $V(y_1,y_2) = {1 \over 2} (m y_1^2 +k (y_2-{mg \over k})^2)$
and consider $\phi(t) = V(\dot{x}(t), x(t))$, where
$t \mapsto x(t)$ is a solution of the differential equation.

$\phi$ represents the kinetic & potential energy of the system.

A quick computation shows that $\dot{\phi} = 0$, hence $V$ is constant on
trajectories of the differential equation.

For $c \ge 0$, the set $V^{-1} \{c\}$ describes an ellipse centred on $(0, -{mg \over k})$.

If we let $y_1=\dot{x}, y_2 = x$, we can write the differential equation as the first order equation:
$\dot{y} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & - { k \over m} \\
1 & 0\end{bmatrix} y + \begin{bmatrix}g \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$. A little work shows that if $V(\dot{x}(0), x(0)) \neq 0$ there there is some $\underline{v} >0$  such that $\|\dot{y}(t)\| \ge \underline{v}$ for all $t \ge 0$, hence the trajectory is continuously moving on the translated ellipse. Hence the
oscillatory nature of the solution.

Note that a one dimensional (time invariant) system cannot exhibit an
oscillatory nature.

Comment: Fickle. ${}{}{}$